# How do i implement n-gram comparison technique in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, comparison

I have a database with millions of record. I want to match input name with names existing in database.For this I would like to use 2-grams technique.

Is there any inbuilt function for implementing this.

I want a single query to return score for all the matching names.

Comment: I don't know of any Oracle n-gram techniques but the [UTL_MATCH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_match.htm) package will let you calculate Jaro-Winkler distance which will give you a single score for comparing names. Or you can use [Oracle Text](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96517/cdefault.htm) to compare text and do full text searches (although this sounds like overkill for your requirements).

Comment: algorithms in UTL_MATCH and Oracle text does not give desired results. I  2-gram gave good results while using java code. But as the actual records are over 10 million it won't be feasible to use java code for comparison. I want the oracle to do that for me (or how do I store the String so that comparison takes least time ).

Comment: If you have a Java solution then you can look at re-using the code within the database - see [CREATE JAVA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5013.htm) statement. (and if the Java uses particular data structures then you can see whether you can recreate any of those that are necessary for repeated matching in the database).